# Pull to refresh returns empty array in Swift 3 iOS 10

Tags: ios10, swift2

I have recently migrated my iOS app to support iOS 10 with Swift 2.3 and have encountered an issue which was previously working fine on iOS 9 / Swift.

Problem goes like this:

I have a `UITableView` which loads up sections and rows, at the first instance everything loads fine. But when I do a pull to refresh i am clearing out the array by `totalSectionData.removeAllObjects()`. now when the refresh is executed it is throwing an error `[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array`. It is obvious I am calling the function to reload the data from server after clearing out the array.
On further investigating and putting breakpoints I found that it is not going inside `numberOfSectionsInTableView` and `numberOfRowsInSection` while I do refresh; On the first time it does goes inside it. `tableView` and delegate are connected properly.
If i comment `totalSectionData.removeAllObjects()` then it works fine but I get duplicate rows.

**It was working fine on previous iOS 9 / Swift 2, I tested the code again on previous version to double confirm.**

Is there anything that's new in iOS 10 / Swift 2.3 that I am missing / doing wrong way.

Refresh code:

```
func refresh(sender:AnyObject)
{
    // Code to refresh table view
    tableView.allowsSelection = false
totalSectionData.removeAllObjects()
    get_data_from_url(json_data_url)
}
```

After the JSON data is received I am calling reloadData

```
func do_table_refresh()
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        self.refreshControl.endRefreshing()

          self.hideActivityIndicator()
        self.tableView.allowsSelection = true
        return
    })
}
// Fetch JSON

func get_data_from_url(url:String)
{

    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"
    request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringCacheData

    tableView.allowsSelection = false

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
         data, response, error) in

        guard let _:NSData = data, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        self.showActivityIndicator()

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
            let json = NSString(data: data!, encoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding)
            self.extract_json(json!)
           // self.activityIndicator.stopAnimating()
            return
        })

    }

    task.resume()

}
func extract_json(data:NSString)
{
    var parseError: NSError?
    let jsonData:NSData = data.dataUsingEncoding(NSASCIIStringEncoding)!
    let json: AnyObject?
    do {
        json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData, options: [])
    } catch let error as NSError {
        parseError = error
        json = nil
    }
    if (parseError == nil)
    {
        if let list:NSArray = json as? NSArray
        {
                 print ("Inside if let")
            let lblArray:NSArray  = (list.valueForKey("level_number") as?NSArray)!
            let data = NSOrderedSet(array: lblArray as [AnyObject])
            for value in data {
                let resultPredicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "level_number == %d", value.integerValue)
                let arrayData:NSArray = list.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate)
                let lblArray:NSArray  = (arrayData.valueForKey("part_number") as?NSArray)!
                let dataValue = NSOrderedSet(array: lblArray as [AnyObject])
                for index in dataValue {
                    let resultPredicate : NSPredicate = NSPredicate(format: "part_number == %d", index.integerValue)
                    totalSectionData.addObject(arrayData.filteredArrayUsingPredicate(resultPredicate))
                }
            }

            for i in 0 ..< list.count
            {
                if let data_block = list[i] as? NSDictionary
                {


                    TableData.append(datastruct(add: data_block))
                }
            }

            do
            {
                try read()
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            do_table_refresh()

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Where are you calling tableview.reloadData()..?? Try to post some code to understand clearly about what you are doing wrong.

Comment: The issue can also be that when you are calling an web API, the response is not getting saved in the array totalSectionData. Please post code for refresh also.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Most important thing is the same thing was working perfectly ok in iOS 9.3 and Swift 2. I've posted the refresh code in my question now. If i comment the `totalSectionData.removeAllObjects()` then everything works fine on refresh also and I get duplicate rows. I have double checked it on a different mac running on Xcode 7 and it works just fine.

Comment: @unexpectedNil : Thanks for the reply, I have added all the code to give you better idea of the issue. But this issue I am facing after migrating to Swift 2.3 / iOS 10. Previously it was working fine.

Comment: @gurmandeep: wanted to add,, if the WebAPI was not giving a response then the code should fail at the first time also in viewDidLoad. The one difference that I could find after putting breakpoints is that on reloadData numberOfSections and numberOfRows is not getting called and it is getting called at the viewDidLoad event.

Comment: I could find a workaround solution to it by adding following line of code in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`       `if (totalSectionData.count > 0) {  // code to update cell goes here }`  I still don't know though why it is working fine in iOS 9.3 and not on iOS 10.

Comment: Did you check that on reload, elements/objects are getting added into totalSectionData